# How to make a cavity in a stone?

Tags: powertools, stone, rock

I'm installing a firewood rack outside, and want for one side of it to stand on a large stone we have there.

The boulder is irregularly shaped and the metal legs of the rack may slip off -- so I'd like to make depressions in the rock for the legs. The depressions need not be very deep -- I think, half of an inch would do.

I tried applying a chisel with a hammer, and got nowhere -- just a little bit of rock dust flying off. I think, the rock is too hard.

Are there any alternatives? I thought of applying a drill with [diamond-tipped "circular saw"](https://smile.amazon.com/DAMO-Diamond-Concrete-Granite-Marble/dp/B005IEIUSC/), but that -- even after I cut a circle -- would still leave the inside of the circle in place, because I'm not going *through* the rock.

I'm sure, this is a solved problem already -- what's the solution?

Comment: You are on the right track. Once you cut a circular groove (maybe 1/4 inch), a whack with a chisel sideways (or a few at different angles) will
 remove most of the center of the circle.

Comment: Any reason a regular hammer drill with the correct drill bit wouldn't work?

Comment: @brhans -- are there stone-bits for hammer drills? I do not have one...

Comment: @bib -- the legs of the rack are rectangular about 1/2"x1", so the circle would need to be about 1.2" in diameter. Do you think, a chisel can just wack such a chunk out?

Comment: A masonry bit typically used on concrete and brick should work.

Comment: Yes. It may take several shots from different angles. I often use a pointed chisel to get a start, and then a flat chisel once there is an edge to grab. Need masonry chisels and a small sledge hammer (or a very hefty ball peen).

Comment: Ok, what about a [rotary drill](https://smile.amazon.com/Hiltex-10513-Rotary-Demolition-Chisels/dp/B000QBR4M0/) -- with a flat chisel?